# Linker error LNK2038: mismatch detected in Release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, pcre, release-mode

I am trying to port a small app of mine from Win XP and VS 2005 to Win 7 and VS 2010.

The app compiles and runs smoothly in Debug mode, however in Release mode I get the following error:

```
pcrecpp.lib(pcrecpp.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 
'_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in LoginDlg.obj
```

Where should I start checking?

Comment: Have you don a "clean" first?

Comment: This happens when some of your projects are being compiled in Debug mode and some in Release. Make sure that all of them are in the same mode.

Comment: Incidentally, I did a clean build and it DID fix the problem, so if some passing reader hasn't yet:  Give it a shot.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your app is being compiled in release mode, but you're linking against the debug version of PCRE, which had /MTd (or similar) set, thus causing the mismatch in iterator debugging level in the CRT.

Recompile PCRE in release mode to match your own application.

The [`detect_mismatch` pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956429.aspx) in VS 2010 is what causes this error to be emitted.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/06/23/stl-performance.aspx (search for _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL)

Answer (score 25):

I had the same error. In my case the solution is easy: I had one project A depending on another project B. B had a preprocessor definition _DEBUG in debug mode and A didn't.

Just add _DEBUG to project A(project->properties->c++->preprocessor->preprocessor definitions) and you're done.

Comment: Thank you! Or in release mode you might have `NDEBUG` defined in one and not the other.

Answer (score 6):

This can also be caused by setting the preprocessor definition `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0` in project B and not in A where A produces a lib used by B.

Comment: What if the problematic lib is a 3rd party software?

Comment: @TomášZato Then  either compile with the same options or request them to compile one for you.  At work, I have made request to compile just for us and the 3rd party did it.

Answer (score 4):

My problem was that dependent project used "Use Multi-Byte Character Set"
under Generl-->Character set. while other project had "No Set" value

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was caused by a missing project reference.

Presumably adding the conflicting project as a reference allowed the build system to make sure that the correct configuration (debug/release) was built.