# Cannot compile my code when using GoogleTest with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, googletest

I have the following problem, I am trying to add testing the my project and opted for GTest.
Downloaded from nuget like all the mortals and while compiling have the following error:

```
 error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1900' in Source.obj
```

Followed by quite a few unresolved external linking errors.
As far as I understand there is a versioning problem here, but none of the answers on SO was useful for me.
This is the simplest example I use:

```
#define _SILENCE_TR1_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATION_WARNING  1
#define GTEST_LANG_CXX11 1

#include <iostream>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

struct Account 
{
    int balance;
    Account() = default;
    explicit Account(const int& bal) :
        balance{ bal } 
    {}
};

TEST(AccountTest, AccountEmpty) 
{
    Account acc;
    EXPECT_EQ(0, acc.balance);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

**VS version 2019

GTest version 1.7.0**

Has anyone has encountered this issue or does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Sources.cpp is your file, not gtest's. Show the compiler options and toolchain used. I guess your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061929/linker-error-lnk2038-mismatch-detected-in-release-mode/4061953.

Comment: `#define GTEST_LANG_CXX11 1` must not be used. Set the appropriate compiler setting `/Zc:__cplusplus`.

Comment: You need a newer GTest version.